# How I can interact with Chainlink "Google Weather Oracle" from a Solana onchain program?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, rust, chainlink

From this link "https://docs.chain.link/docs/any-api/data-providers/google-weather/" I can only see an example given for solidity smart contract. I have been searching for materials or links that contains concrete examples for integrating rust smart contract with Chainlink "Google Weather Oracle" but I can't seem to find any.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the available feeds on their docs: https://docs.chain.link/docs/solana/data-feeds-solana/, it looks like weather data is not included.  Here's the current list:

```
Pair    Asset   Type    Address

BTC / USD   Bitcoin     Crypto  CGmWwBNsTRDENT5gmVZzRu38GnNnMm1K5C3sFiUUyYQX
ETH / USD   Ethereum    Crypto  5WyTBrEgvkAXjTdYTLY9PVrztjmz4edP5W9wks9KPFg5
LINK / USD  Chainlink   Crypto  EH32v4UHcwH6S7gLTRvEBEyCTJrVbhRiJE7QEGoqd4NU
SOL / USD   Solana  Crypto  CcPVS9bqyXbD9cLnTbhhHazLsrua8QMFUHTutPtjyDzq
SRM / USD   Serum   Crypto  2v4qnkskmnXjeYRQkdFTPLPsU42vhG1tAKbRvw7Vqjij
USDC / USD  Circle USD  Crypto  7CLo1BY41BHAVnEs57kzYMnWXyBJrVEBPpZyQyPo2p1G
USDT / USD  Tether USD  Crypto  76npM99oWkDXdepEJLXc3chmya2n1tEZzqfU2n67nywS
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the valuable feedback, this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm YY (BD) from Switchboard - a permissionless oracle protocol for general purpose data feeds & Verifiable Random Function (VRF).

In terms of permissionless-ness, you can build your own data feeds via our [Publisher](https://app.switchboard.xyz) and you can fetch any API/public endpoint from off-chain to on-chain, be it price, sports, weather data.

Some templates are ready to use in our Catalog (the page you see immediately), here's one of it, [San_Francisco_Degree_Celcius](https://app.switchboard.xyz/share/0c501870ff141492b1422b0297be22fa19bff0936a7f1a9a6824496bc49eaf29/devnet)

To build custom feeds, we have a [custom build tool](https://app.switchboard.xyz/build/tool) with drag-n-drop task types.

Feel free to reach out to us on [Discord](https://discord.gg/switchboardxyz) for further queries

Comment: This is really great, I will definitely check out the templates to understand how they work. Thanks so much for your input.